# What is IE's Maximum Parallel Connection Accross All Hosts

Tags: internet-explorer

Based on the IE documentation on MSDN IE 8 supports up to 6 parallel connections per server and IE 6,7 support 2.

What is the upper limit of parallel connections accross all the hosts? So if I have 60 hosts, 8 requests per host, so 360 requests in the HTML page - does it mean that IE 8 will have 360 connection in parallel and IE 6 or 7 would have 120? (ignoring the html rendering time, and if call is blocking or not)

Comment: Just curious why you're trying to calculate this.

Comment: I am simply trying to understand what impacts the performance of a page, if i have to many objects referenced in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't have an overall limit, although it currently applies the max-connections-per-host limit as a max-connections-per-proxy-limit, so if you have a fixed proxy server, there's a very low limit.

A post on this topic is headed to my blog shortly.  http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/

Comment: Eric, did you ever do this post in your blog?

Comment: Hi Eric, I was looking for an answer to the same question. Did you ever get to post something on this topic? I was unable to find the answer on your blog.